# Execute the outer query for each date obtained from inner query

Tags: sql

I have the following table BOOKSALES.
Some Background about the attributes -

1. BookID - The unique ID of the book
2. SaleDate - Date on which the book was sold
3. RegisterDate - Date on which sale was registered in accounts books

The table looks like this -

```
+--------+------------+--------------+
| BOOKID | SALEDATE   | REGISTERDATE |
+--------+------------+--------------+
| A1     | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-01   |
| A2     | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-02   |
| A3     | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-03   |
| A4     | 2021-03-02 | 2021-03-02   |
| A5     | 2021-03-02 | 2021-03-03   |
| A6     | 2021-03-03 | 2021-03-03   |
| A7     | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-01   |
| A8     | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-02   |
+--------+------------+--------------+
```

Now I want to execute the query that gives me the count of book ids for each sale date, but the register date is less than the sale date.
For example-
If I want to execute the query for 2nd March, the query will look like-

```
SELECT COUNT(BOOKID) FROM BOOKSALES WHERE SALEDATE>='2021-03-01' AND SALEDATE<='2021-03-02' AND REGISTERDATE<='2021-03-02';
```

I want to execute the above query for each date in March . So I tried to rephrase the query as follows

```
SELECT SALEDATE,COUNT(BOOKID) FROM BOOKSALES WHERE SALEDATE>='2021-03-01' AND (SALEDATE AND REGISTERDATE)<=(SELECT DISTINCT(SALEDATE) FROM BOOKSALES WHERE SALEDATE>='2021-03-01' AND SALEDATE<='2021-03-31')  ORDER BY SALEDATE GROUP BY SALEDATE;
```

But the above query doesn't seem to work. Can somebody suggest how to write the above query correctly?

The eventual output should look like -

```
+------------+---------------+
| SALEDATE   | COUNT(BOOKID) |
+------------+---------------+
| 2021-03-01 |             1 |
+------------+---------------+
| 2021-03-02 |             3 |
+------------+---------------+
| 2021-03-03 |             6 |
+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Are you calculating the running sum of counts for the count? by what logic did you get count value 3 on 2021-03-02 and count value 6 on 2021-03-03?

Comment: I think by running sum you mean cumulative sum. In that case Yes.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(BOOKID) FROM BOOKSALES WHERE SALEDATE>='2021-03-01' AND SALEDATE<='2021-03-02' AND REGISTERDATE<='2021-03-02'; gives the count as 3.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(BOOKID) FROM BOOKSALES WHERE SALEDATE>='2021-03-01' AND SALEDATE<='2021-03-03' AND REGISTERDATE<='2021-03-03'; gives the count as 6

Comment: @TedoG. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of the task is a bit unclear, can't see what are you trying to achieve. Anyways, your desired output can be returned with this query:

```
SELECT A.SALEDATE, COUNT(*)
FROM 
(SELECT SALEDATE
FROM BOOKSALES
WHERE SALEDATE BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-03-31'
GROUP BY SALEDATE
) AS A
INNER JOIN BOOKSALES AS B
ON A.SALEDATE >= B.REGISTRATION_DATE
GROUP BY A.SALEDATE
```

Comment: SELECT SALEDATE,COUNT(BOOKID) FROM BOOKSALES WHERE SALEDATE>='2021-03-01' AND (SALEDATE AND REGISTERDATE)<=(SELECT DISTINCT(SALEDATE) FROM BOOKSALES WHERE SALEDATE>='2021-03-01' AND SALEDATE<='2021-03-31') ORDER BY SALEDATE GROUP BY SALEDATE; Can you correct this query?

Comment: '(SALEDATE AND REGISTERDATE)<= x' this is where you will get the error. You can not compare two columns to a value like that. As an alternative, you can write both comparisons separately: SALEDATE <= x AND REGISTERDATE <= x

Comment: That is the main problem I am facing. The inner query value - (SELECT DISTINCT(SALEDATE) FROM BOOKSALES WHERE SALEDATE>='2021-03-01' AND SALEDATE<='2021-03-31') has to be compared with both SALEDATE AND REGISTERDATE. How do I compare it with both?

Comment: SELECT SALEDATE,COUNT(BOOKID) FROM BOOKSALES WHERE SALEDATE>='2021-03-01' AND (SALEDATE AND REGISTERDATE)<=(SELECT DISTINCT(SALEDATE) FROM BOOKSALES WHERE SALEDATE>='2021-03-01' AND SALEDATE<='2021-03-31') ORDER BY SALEDATE GROUP BY SALEDATE; Can you please correct this query?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know exactly how you want to group it. But you do not need a sales registration date when you want the sales date.

```
//all date
SELECT SALEDATE,COUNT(BOOKID) FROM BOOKSALES GROUP BY SALEDATE

//march month
SELECT SALEDATE,COUNT(BOOKID) FROM BOOKSALES WHERE Month(SALEDATE) = 03 GROUP BY SALEDATE
```

Or so

```
SELECT SALEDATE,COUNT(BOOKID) 
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT SALEDATE FROM BOOKSALES WHERE Month(SALEDATE) = 03) T1
JOIN
BOOKSALES T2 ON T1.SALEDATE = T2.SALEDATE
GROUP BY SALEDATE
ORDER BY SALEDATE
```

Comment: Hi meysam. Actually, I want the following query SELECT COUNT(BOOKID) FROM BOOKSALES WHERE SALEDATE>='2021-03-01' AND SALEDATE<=x AND REGISTERDATE<=x; to be run for all dates in March. ( x can be replaced by any march date)

Comment: I checked. Your query is correct. Where is the problem now?

Comment: Which query did you check?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(BOOKID) FROM BOOKSALES WHERE SALEDATE>='2021-03-01' AND SALEDATE<=x AND REGISTERDATE<=x group by SALEDATE

Comment: Actually, my doubt is how do I automate the query so that it runs for every march date?

Comment: SELECT SALEDATE,COUNT(BOOKID) FROM BOOKSALES WHERE SALEDATE>='2021-03-01' AND (SALEDATE AND REGISTERDATE)<=(SELECT DISTINCT(SALEDATE) FROM BOOKSALES WHERE SALEDATE>='2021-03-01' AND SALEDATE<='2021-03-31')  ORDER BY SALEDATE GROUP BY SALEDATE; Can you correct this query?

Comment: @Dawson Smith The query I wrote automatically returns the months of March.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to just want aggregation:

```
SELECT SALEDATE, COUNT(*)
FROM BOOKSALES
WHERE SALEDATE >= '2021-03-01' AND SALEDATE < '2021-04-01' 
GROUP BY SALEDATE;
```

I don't see that the restriction comparing SALEDATE and REGISTERDATE is needed.  You can, of course, add that in.